# Find the push forward of the stereographic projection

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

**Problem:** Given the set, $$ S_1^2 = \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb{R}^3 | x^2 + y^2 + (z-1)^2=1\}$$
and $\pi: S_1^2 \setminus N \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^2 $, such that:

$$ \pi (x,y,z) = \left(\frac{2x}{2-z},\frac{2y}{2-z}\right)$$

> Prove that  $\pi$ transforms the u-parametric curves of the sphere, into circunferences in the plane $\Bbb{R}^2$, and that  $\pi$ transforms the v-parametric curves of the sphere, into lines. Make a diagram of the situation, and include how tangent vectors are transfo.rmed into tangent vectors in the plane (meaning, find the push-forward)

**My advances:** I would like to solve this problem, by understanding what do I have to do and the algorithms that I have to do. As I understand, first, I should parametrize the set $S_1^2$ by using $f(u,v) = \left(r \cos u \cos v, r \cos u \sin v, r \sin u\right)$, 
$v \in [0, 2\pi], u \in [0, \pi]$, where $r=1$, Or maybe I am supposed to use the 2-chart parametrization of the sphere.

what is the correct approach?

Secondly, i beleive I shoud compute the Jacobian of $f$ and multiply it by a vector, i don't know which vector. My guess comes from inspecting the example: [Pushforward of a vector field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505132/pushforward-of-a-vector-field) , but I am not yet able to apply this to my example.

My intuitive understanding of the pushforward is that it sends tangent vectors to tangent vectors, that is clear, but I would like to be able to find out how to make the computations for" $\pi$ transforms the u-parametric curves of the sphere, into circunferences in the plane $\Bbb{R}^2$, and that  $\pi$ transforms the v-parametric curves of the sphere, into lines."

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\bullet$ Yes, I would first use the $2$-parameter parametrization. However the $f$ that you give, parametrizes the sphere with center at $(0,0,0)$. You need the one where the center is $(0,0,1)$. You should have,

$$ f(u,v) = \begin{pmatrix} \cos u \cos v \\ \cos u \sin v \\  \sin u + 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}$$

Now we have $x^2+ y^2 + (z-1)^2 = 1$. We can now write,

\begin{align*} \pi(x,y,z) &= (\pi \circ f)(u,v)\\&:= g(u,v) = \left (\frac{2 \cos u \cos v}{2-(\sin u + 1)}, \frac{2\cos u \sin v}{2-(\sin u + 1)}\right) = \begin{pmatrix} s \\ t \end{pmatrix}\end{align*}

$\bullet$ For the push-forward, you just need to calculate the differential $D_p \pi$ and apply it to $X_p$ where $X_p$ is a tangent vector at $p \in S^2_1$. You have a map $f$ which allows you to calculate tangent vectors on $S^2_1$, simply by taking its derivative i.e,

$$ X_p = \alpha \cdot f_u(u,v) + \beta \cdot f_v(u,v)$$

Now you push this vector forward with the linear map $D_{f(u,v)} \pi$.

$$D_{f(u,v)} \pi = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{2x}{2-z}\right) &\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(\frac{2x}{2-z}\right) & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \left(\frac{2x}{2-z}\right)\\\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{2y}{2-z}\right) &\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(\frac{2y}{2-z}\right) & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \left(\frac{2y}{2-z}\right)\end{pmatrix}_{f(u,v)}$$

That is, after you compute the entries, plug in the coordinate functions $x,y,z$ of $f(u,v)$. Then apply that matrix to $X_p$.

$$D_{f(u,v)}\pi \ \big(X_p\big) = \alpha \cdot D_{f(u,v)}\pi \big(f_u(u,v)\big) + \beta \cdot D_{f(u,v)} \pi \big(f_v(u,v)\big)$$